# Use result of ob-shell block in subsequent ob-shell block

Tags: org-babel

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
aws ec2 describe-instances
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
i-0154b911d1f4e0871

#+BEGIN_SRC sh
aws ec2 terminate-instances "param1"
#+END_SRC
```

How can I use the result of the first block as the parameter (param1) of the `aws ec2 terminate-instances` statement?